# Multiple request mapping on controller Spring Hateos

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, hateoas, request-mapping

While in Spring MVC `@requestmapping(value={"url1","url2"})` is allowed but Spring `HATEOS` picks the first mapping while creating link. Is there any solution in which request mapping version on the controller matches with the http request version call.

Suppose both `url1` and `url2` have different version and put on the same controller.
The controller internally creates a link for another controller. For both urls, it use the first request mapping from the controller. But i want it should be according to url calls. For `url1` it should use version 1 and For `url2` it should use version 2.

### First Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("url/v1","ur1/v2")
public class MyFirstController{
    public Response<Entity> method1(){
          return ResponseEntity<AnotherResponseType>(
           new AnotherResponseType(argument1, argument2), HttpStatus.OK);

     }
 }
```

### Second Controller

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("url/v1","ur1/v2")
 public class MySecondController{
       public Response<ResponseType> method1(){
                return ResponseEntity<ResponseType>(
               new ResponseType(argument1, argument2), HttpStatus.OK);  
 }}
```

ResponseType uses Spring HATEOS to create the link. In case of call for version v2, this response always contains the version v1 in the link created instead of version v2.

### ResponseType

```
 class ResponseType{
       public Response Type(String argument1, String argument2){
        this.add(inkTo(methodOn(MyFirstController.class).method1(argument1, 
         null).withRel("link1"));
          }
   }
```

What i want is to get the link created for v2 should contains v2 instead of v1?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you add code and example ,your question is very confusing.

Comment: @vaquarkhan sample code added. LMK if any other information required.

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder class have set of method which you can use to build a link like

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;

resource.add(linkTo(AuthorController.class).slash(author.getAuthorId()).slash("books").withRel("vaquar"));

// or by pointing directly to a controller method
resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(UserController.class).getUsers(author.getUserId())).withRel("vaquar"));
```

You can read [here](https://dzone.com/articles/exposing-and-managing-links)

Working example : https://github.com/corsoft/spring-hateoas-demo